# Angular2 - Upgrade from beta 17 to stable version (2.0.0)

Tags: angular

i was looking for a tutorial or something to get my code upgraded from the beta to the stable version. I did not find anything related to upgrade from beta 17.

The code has 2400+ lines of code. Do i need to change something?

Also do i need to change paths?

I would appreciate some sort of tutorial or info to upgrade it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions about external resources like tutorials, libraries, books, ... are discouraged on SO. Please check the help menu about what questions (not) to ask. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md is probably the best answer to your question.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://proudmonkey.azurewebsites.net/upgrading-from-angularjs-2-beta-to-rc-6/